# Tridion Powertools Script Errors (2009)

Tags: tridion

Installed the Powertools on a dev '09 system - now I get the script error "Unable to set the value of property 'async' : object is null or undefined"

I'm thinking this is possibly because I'm using IE9 in compat mode which I don't believe is supported?

Thanks

Comment: Can you load the individual powertools by URL? That first page of the power tools has way too many hacks in it...

Comment: Yeah, seems to work - I'd like to let users use the URI tree though, if possible; but if not, then I'll ditch it.

Comment: yeah, seen that before, can't remember how I fixed it. Not much knowledge around here on those .asp files anymore...

Comment: try adding the CMS URL to `Local Intranet`. IE Options --> Security --> Local Intranet --> Sites --> Advanced .. add CMS URL. I got it working by making that change in the past.

Comment: Do you get this when you try to open the item selectie pop-up?

Comment: @Mapton, Could you please take a look at the answer below and let us if it helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The PowerTools ItemSelector (`itemselector.asp`) uses MSXML2 to make HTTP Connection. The `GetXMLHTTPRequest` does an async call using the XMLHTTP and seems like this is failing in your case.

I have IE 9 (ver: 9.0.8112) and the Powertools Item Selector is working in both normal and compatibility mode. The reason for this (I am assuming) that I have MXSML2 installed.

I used this link to check what MSXML version I have : http://www.bayes.co.uk/xml/utils/msxml_sniffer.htm

**Output from my machine when I used the URL:**

```
MSXML        Installed 
MSXML2       Installed 
MSXML2 v2.6  Automation server can't create object 
MSXML2 v3.0  Installed 
MSXML2 v4.0  Installed 
MSXML2 v5.0  Installed 
MSXML2 v6.0  Installed 
Mode         Replace V3
```

If you check the MSXML version from your browser you should get the similar output. The key here is MSXML2.

In Addition to MXSML, the second one is your browser security. I have to make the below settings for ItemSelector to work, otherwise it just show an empty popup with no publications.

IE Local Intranet settings. IE Options --> Security --> Local Intranet --> Sites --> Advanced , then Add the CMS URL as local intranet.

Hope this helps.